# Spring RMI to remote to other

Tags: java, spring-integration

how can I connect to other system using rmi in Spring Remoting. is there any way to connect it ?

I Used the spring rmi concept but i did n,t get it.

How to give host name and ip address in spring configuration file.

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you fully understand what is [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), but you should check the tag next time when start the question.

Anyway you may go the right way, because yes, Spring Integration provides [RMI Adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/rmi.html), too:

```
<int-rmi:outbound-gateway id="gateway"
    request-channel="localChannel"
    remote-channel="testChannel"
    host="localhost"/>
```

With raw Spring configuration it looks like:

```
<bean id="accountService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://HOST:1199/AccountService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.AccountService"/>
</bean>
```